# Cannot find supervisor and gen_servers in Erlang observer

Tags: erlang, gen-server, erlang-supervisor

I'm running a simple supervisor with a couple of children and I want to see how the supervisor tree structure looks using Erlang Observer. I start the Erlang shell, initiate the supervisor and then call `observer:start()` from the shell where I can see this tree like processes structure in Applications tab.

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot see my supervisor (called `animal_sup`) in this at all. I can however see it in the processes where it shows like this
[image]

and it shows that the parent process of the process is <0.79.0>.
[image]

but I can't see this process in the tree shown in the Applications tab either. I can't seem to figure out how this process is different and how can I find my supervisor in the Applications tab.